# Output large Json object and System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I need to send response of binary data(file) as JSON response in ASP.NET(IIS7) application and I use JsonObject object from System.Net.Json(comes with .NET 4.x) for that. Unfortunately sometimes I get out of memory exception.

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at System.Net.Json.JsonUtility.EscapeString(String text)
   at System.Net.Json.JsonStringValue.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Net.Json.JsonCollection.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Net.Json.JsonObject.ToString()
   at System.Web.HttpWriter.Write(Object obj)
   at WebClient.Processor.FillResponse(HttpContext context, Object entity, OutputTypes outputType)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at WebClient.Processor.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

The code

```
JsonUtility.GenerateIndentedJsonText = true;
var jsonObject = new JsonObjectCollection();
context.Response.ContentType = JsonUtility.MimeType;
var jsonStringValue = new JsonStringValue("File", Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length));
jsonObject.Add(jsonStringValue);
context.Response.Write(jsonObject);
```

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the the memory limits and recycling time setting of the application pool in IIS.

Comment: Private Memory Limit is set to 0 (unlimited) and recycle is disabled at all.